# Example of system architecture picture in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, nodes

I am looking for an example of a system architecture diagram in TikZ. I would like to draw a picture similar to this one:
[image]

Therefore I search for existing shapes for: *cloud* (Current State), *database* and *document collection* (Confs) or a way to learn how to draw them.

Comment: Both are (almost) natively supported in Tikz 2.1 by the shape library: For clouds see the shape type `cloud`, described on pp. 435f. For a document-type node see the shape type `tape` on p. 440 of the [PGF manual](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf). The latter can be typeset a number of times to get the stack of documents (aka document collection).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `cloud` and the `cylinder` are in the shape libraries.  See Sections 48.3 and 48.4 of the TikZ 2.10 manual.

The document collection shape you'll have to put together yourself, though. You can super-impose rectangles and then a `tape` shape on top of that.

Comment: Thx. Could you provide an example of superimposed rectangles?